# How do i download pdf file over https with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, pdf, pdf-generation

I am writing a python script, which will save pdf file locally according to the format given in URL. for eg.

```
https://Hostname/saveReport/file_name.pdf   #saves the content in PDF file.
```

I am opening this URL through python script :

```
 import webbrowser
 webbrowser.open("https://Hostname/saveReport/file_name.pdf")
```

The url contains lots of images and text. **Once this URL is opened i want to save a file in pdf format using python script.**

This is what i have done so far.
Code 1:

```
import requests
url="https://Hostname/saveReport/file_name.pdf"    #Note: It's https
r = requests.get(url, auth=('usrname', 'password'), verify=False)
file = open("file_name.pdf", 'w')
file.write(r.read())
file.close()
```

Code 2:

```
 import urllib2
 import ssl
 url="https://Hostname/saveReport/file_name.pdf"
 context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
 response = urllib2.urlopen(url, context=context)  #How should i pass authorization details here?
 html = response.read()
```

In above code i am getting: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

If i use Code 2, how can i pass authorization details?

Comment: Do you want a solution using `webbrowser.open`, `requests.get`, or `urllib2.urlopen`?

Comment: @Robᵩ - I have tried above approaches. So requests or urllib2 anything will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this will work, you can just pass the auth into requests.get ... then just write the raw content into a new pdf file

```
import requests
import shutil
url="https://Hostname/saveReport/file_name.pdf"    #Note: It's https
r = requests.get(url, auth=('usrname', 'password'), verify=False,stream=True)
r.raw.decode_content = True
with open("file_name.pdf", 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: Can you leave some explanation?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do that is:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = r"https://websitewithfile.com/file.pdf"
fileName = r"file.pdf"
with urllib3.PoolManager() as http:
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(r.data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like :

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://websitewithfile.com/file.pdf',verify=False, auth=('user', 'pass'))
with open('file.pdf','w') as fout:
   fout.write(response.read()):
```

Comment: `response.text` is probably a bad choice, since it involves a decoding step. Maybe open the file with `wb` and write `response.content` instead.

Comment: response.raw  I think

Comment: Apparently, `response.iter_chunk` is `request`'s "preferred and recommended way to retrieve a document": http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content

Comment: I edited with a better way of getting response content

Answer (score -1):

For some files - at least tar archives (or even all other files) you can use pip:

```
import sys
from subprocess import call, run, PIPE
url = "https://blabla.bla/foo.tar.gz"
call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "download", url], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

But you should confirm that the download was successful some other way as pip would raise error for any files that are not archives containing setup.py, hence stderr=PIPE (Or may be you can determine if the download was successful by parsing subprocess error message).